# How to pass a dropdown value to a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass the selected value of a dropdown to a partial view.

Here is the ActionResult that is called

```
public ActionResult AddContact(int customerId = 0)
{
    ContactModel contact = new ContactModel();
    contact.CustomerId = customerId;

    return PartialView(contact);
}
```

Here is the dropdown menu that contains the value needed

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerId, new SelectList(Model.CustomerOptions, "Key", "Value", Model.CustomerId), new { @id = "category", @name = "category", @class = "select-search" })
```

and here is the Modal popup that we need the parameter for

```
<div id="modal_form_horizontal_addcontact" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-success">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h5 class="modal-title">Add New Contact</h5>
            </div>

            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @{Html.RenderAction("AddContact", "Ticket", new { CustomerId = Model.CustomerId });}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically, the modal popup creates a new contact for a customer thats selected in the dropdown menu. I need the ID of the customer to add the contact to.

Comment: What is `@name = "category"` for? That would override the name of the posted parameter

Comment: @name = "category" is used for some jQuery that pulls contacts for the selected customer. EG Select a customer - Select a contact - select a site

Comment: Well, that's your problem then I believe. You are not posting customerId param back to the action

Comment: It's not a good idea to have `@name` attribute in `DropDownListFor` which will override default naming of the select element. You should use `id` attribute to identify the element instead.